# Stream.last Evaluation

Tags: scala

Let's define a `Stream[Int]` with elements `(1,2,3)`.

```
scala> val x = Stream(1,2,3)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

`x` shows up as `Stream(1, ?)` since, as I understand, it's evaluated on demand, i.e. when necessary.

Then, I call `x.last`.

```
scala> x.last
res0: Int = 3
```

Lastly, I call `x` again to see its value.

```
scala> x
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3)
```

Does `x` equal `Stream(1,2,3)` since I had called `x.last`, resulting in the accessing of all values (going left to right in the list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the APi doc : "The Stream class also employs memoization such that previously computed values are converted from Stream elements to concrete values"

another thing which might be counter intuitive seems to be the contradiciton between the fact that your stream should be immutable... but the doc clearly says "While the Stream is actually being modified during access, this does not change the notion of its immutability. Once the values are memoized they do not change and values that have yet to be memoized still "exist", they simply haven't been realized yet." (taken from : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html)

so in other words you are right =)